# how to grep columns from a txt file and redirect to another text file in shell script

Tags: shell

the file1.txt has the following content separated by "|":-

```
a|b|c|d|e
1|11|111|1111|11111
2|22|222|2222|22222
3|33|333|3333|333333
4|44|444|4444|44444
```

How to grep only columns a, c and d and redirect into another file file2.txt ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on exactly what you want, there are a couple of options.

### Extracting Columns, Then Filtering

The most straightforward is if you just want `2|222|2222` in your output.  The `cut` command selects columns based on a delimiter, and `grep` handles the rows.

```
cut -f1,3,5 -d'|' infile.txt | grep '2222' > outfile.txt
```

However, that'll be a slight problem, if you ever need to find `3` but *not* `3333`.  You might want to use `grep -w` to only search for complete words, but you also might not, if you're trying to find a substring.

### Variation, Better Searching

If you're willing to work in multiple lines and want to output the *entire* line from the source file, you can ask `grep` for line numbers.

```
for line in $(cut -f3 -d'|' infile.txt | grep -wn '222' | cut -f1 -d':')
do
  sed -n "${line}p" infile.txt > outfile.txt
done
```

There are many ways to get the 307th line of a file, but `sed -n '307p'` is probably the most readable and the easiest to extend to a range of lines, by changing the number to a comma-delimited pair like `'300,310p'`.

### Use `awk`

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) describes `awk` as...

> ...a domain-specific language designed for text processing and typically used as a data extraction and reporting tool.

...so, it's fairly ideal for this sort of work, even if it comes with a more difficult learning curve.  Here, you'll need to actually learn the language or provide more extensive details about what you want (ideally in a new question, to prevent scope-creep, here), but something like the following should get you started.

```
awk -F\| '{ if ($4 == "2222") print $0 }' infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

The `-F` parameter is the field separator/delimiter, the in-language `$*` items are fields, with `$0` being the full line.

### Just the Columns

After a quick discussion in the comments, if you only want specific columns from the file, that's just a piece of the first solution.

```
cut -f1,3,5 -d'|' infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

In this case, `cut` just takes the comma-delimited list of columns---delimited with whatever you feed the `-d` parameter---and outputs the columns as text.

Comment: i want all the rows but only the columns a c and e should be extracted. i am not putting any condition in the rows

Comment: @Aviator, ah, that's a simpler problem.  I added a solution to the bottom of the answer with just `cut` that should do what you want.  It's basically the first solution, without the `grep` command.